# Automatic window title update

Tags: cygwin

Is there a mechanism that could set the title of the cgywin window based on the current value of an environment variable?

I found this small script sometime ago (on SO I think) that allows the window title to be set to a specific string:

```
echo -ne "\e]2;$@\a\e]1;$@\a";
```

---

*Background*: I have just switched from using Subversion to Perforce (company policy) and find myself repeatedly checking the value of the `P4CLIENT` environment variable to know what my current workspace is. It would be quite useful to have the title of the cygwin window to automatically contain the current value of that environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least if you're using Bash and Mintty, you could check out [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/471661/140335).

So in your case, you could do something like (single quotes changed to double quotes from the original answer since single quotes don't interpolate):

```
echo -ne "\e]0;$P4CLIENT\a"
```

You could then add that line into your `.bashrc` file to make it permanent.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this does not appear to work. I added the line to my `.bashrc` file but it does not update the window title when I change the value of the environment variable. Not sure if this even possible.

Comment: Along with your suggestion and the `PROMPT_COMMAND` mentioned in the post you linked it now works. Thank you very much.